# jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'form' is undefined

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I am trying to add a form in bootstrap modal and the form is created using WTForms but it can't get the context variable in render_template.
I had followed this link ([Flask Mega Tutorial - jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'form' is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19506109/flask-mega-tutorial-jinja2-exceptions-undefinederror-form-is-undefined)) but the problem is not solved yet.

```
# Warehouse
class Warehouse_Add(Form):
    product_name = StringField('Product Name',[validators.Length(min=5,max=10), validators.DataRequired()])
    product_price = StringField('Price',[validators.DataRequired()])
    product_qty = StringField('Quantity',[validators.DataRequired()])

@app.route('/warehouse', methods=['GET','POST'])
def warehouse_add():
    form = Warehouse(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        product_name = form.product_name.data
        product_price = form.product_price.data
        product_qty = form.product_qty.data
        cur = mysql.get_db().cursor()
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO company_warehouse(name, price, qty) VALUES(%s, %s, %s)',(product_name,product_price,product_qty))
        mysql.get_db().commit()
        cur.close()
        flash("Product Added!!","success")
        redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
    return render_template('dashboard.html',form=form)
```

This is the **Python** Code

```
{% from "includes/_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
      <form action="" method="POST">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="form-group row">{{render_field(form.product_name,class_="form-control")}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="form-group row">{{render_field(form.product_price,class_="form-control")}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="form-group row">{{render_field(form.product_qty,class_="form-control")}}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger">Reset</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

This is the **template** part

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide where this 'form undefined error is coming up. So which line of code, or even better the whole stack trace at the moment of the error?

Edit:

As sugested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/19506148/11333207. Try to use the form like this.

```
@app.route('/warehouse', methods=['GET','POST'])
def warehouse_add():

    form = Warehouse()

    if form.validate_on_submit():

        product_name = form.product_name.data
        product_price = form.product_price.data
        product_qty = form.product_qty.data
        cur = mysql.get_db().cursor()
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO company_warehouse(name, price, qty) VALUES(%s, %s, %s)',(product_name,product_price,product_qty))
        mysql.get_db().commit()
        cur.close()
        flash("Product Added!!","success")
        redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
    return render_template('dashboard.html',form=form)
```

Comment: The 'form undefined error' is coming from these lines **{{render_field(form.product_name,class_="form-control")}}** in the html template

Comment: and about the __init__ you had told ok I understood that but I also have a registration template for the same project which also contain WTForm there I had written the same code but that one is working fine

Comment: Ok! The provided answer in your link is not passing any values to PostForm() (your Warehouse_Add()). I edited my answer to a code like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/19506148/11333207

Comment: Also keep in mind: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/patterns/wtforms/, so if you want to pass the form like there you have to retrieve the form correctly. Make sure the method is handling 'POST' and 'GET' correctly.

Comment: every thing is perfect with 'GET' and 'POST' handling but still same result and I had also tried with the given link nothing is making any difference !!